# How to extract Dart/Flutter video metadata

Tags: dart, flutter

I am developing a flutter demo app. I want to use metadata about a video in my phone storage. I am able to extract the path of that video, but don't know how to extract its metadata in dart/flutter.

I need the following metadata:

1. Duration of video
2. Name of video
3. Size of video
4. When video was taken

Comment: Edit for clarity

Answer (score 26, accepted):

You can use the `VideoPlayerController.file` constructor from the official [video player plugin](https://pub.dartlang.org/documentation/video_player/latest/) (which is maintained by the official google team so you don't have to worry about its future and stability) to access the file and get the following meta after you install the package:

first this is your `VideoPlayerController`:

```
 VideoPlayerController controller = new VideoPlayerController.file('');//Your file here
```

1. Duration:

   ```
   controller.value.duration ;
   ```
2. Video Name, this should already be  possessed with you as you can reach the file path and pass it to the player constructor.

3.Video Size:

```
    controller.value.size ;
```

4.As for when the video was taken I can't help you with this. You have to find another way to figure it out.

Comment: controller value showing me null for every parameter I am using file_picker to get path of video.@mazin

Comment: did you provide the controller with your file path ? I left it empty so you can put yours.

Comment: yes.It seems file_picker is giving me the wrong path of file i picked.

Comment: my file-picker gives /storage/emulated/0/Download/25340103_1481179175311062_7853653764400480256_n.mp4  as path of file @MazinIbrahim

Comment: is the `controller` still showing `null` after adding this file ?

Comment: I/flutter (27921): Filepath>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>/storage/emulated/0/Download/25340103_1481179175311062_7853653764400480256_n.mp4
D/mali_winsys(27921): new_window_surface returns 0x3000,  [540x960]-format:1
I/flutter (27921): >>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>VideoPlayerValue(duration: null, size: null, position: 0:00:00.000000, buffered: [], isPlaying: false, isLooping: false, isBuffering: falsevolume: 1.0, errorDescription: null)

Comment: use a `File` variable then pass it to `controller` : var file = new File('/storage/emulated/0/Download/25340103_1481179175311062_7853653764400480256_n.mp4');

Comment: String filePath = await FilePicker.getFilePath(type: FileType.VIDEO);
      if (filePath == '') return;
      print('Filepath>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>' + filePath);
      File file = await File(filePath);
      setState(() => this.filePath = file);
      VideoPlayerController controller =
          new VideoPlayerController.file(file); //Your file here
      print('>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>${controller.value}');

Comment: >>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>VideoPlayerValue(duration: null, size: null, position: 0:00:00.000000, buffered: [], isPlaying: false, isLooping: false, isBuffering: falsevolume: 1.0, errorDescription: null)

Comment: It is important to state that you need to call ```await controller.initialize();``` before trying to obtain those values

Comment: Of course @YanivShaked! Without awaiting the asynchoronous initialization correct values won't be found. At the time of answering I was just referring him to the properties through which he can retrieve needed info. Thank you very much for your note!

Comment: Does it work for network video?

Answer (score 9):

One of the ways to get the creation time of the video in FLutter is to use [flutter_ffmpeg](https://pub.dev/packages/flutter_ffmpeg) plugin.

1. Add it to the `pubspec.yaml`:

   ```
   dependencies:
      flutter_ffmpeg: ^0.3.0
   ```
2. Get the file path of your video, for example with [file_picker](https://pub.dev/packages/file_picker):

   ```
   File pickedFile = await FilePicker.getFile();
   ```
3. Get meta data of the video by its path using ffmpeg:

   ```
    final FlutterFFprobe flutterFFprobe = FlutterFFprobe();
    MediaInformation mediaInformation = await flutterFFprobe.getMediaInformation(pickedFile.path);
    Map<dynamic, dynamic> mp = mediaInformation.getMediaProperties();
    String creationTime = mp["tags"]["creation_time"];
    print("creationTime: $creationTime");
   ```

And in the console you'll get smth like this:

`I/flutter (13274): creationTime: 2020-09-24T17:59:24.000000Z`

Along with creation time, there are other useful details:
[image]

*Note: adding this plugin to your app increases the weight of your final apk!*

Comment: How can we fetch cover image(album art) and other properties of audio files such as artist name, song name, total time length of audio files etc. Please help I am stuck on this for 2 weeks.

Comment: have you tried `flutter_ffmpeg`? It works with audio files as well. That's one of the most powerful libraries to work with video//audio on mobile so far

Comment: The above-mentioned package is discontinued and a new one is created on pub.dev, here is the link: https://pub.dev/packages/ffmpeg_kit_flutter

Comment: ***IMPORTANT WARNING*** 
The package `flutter_ffmpeg` is marked as discontinued.
Prefer use another package instead of this one.

Answer (score 0):

your code is correct Mazin Ibrahim  you just need to initialize it. the future value will return all the details.

```
Future getVideo() async {

   await MultiMediaPicker.pickVideo(source: ImageSource.gallery).then((video){

     File _video = video;
     VideoPlayerController fileVideocontroller = new VideoPlayerController.file(_video)
     ..initialize().then((_) {

       debugPrint("========"+fileVideocontroller.value.duration.toString());
     });
   });
}
```

Comment: Is it gonna give me video creation date time thats my greatest concern,I dont think so